# If I find a bad translation of a standard label in salesforce, how should I report it?

Tags: translation

I'm a 20 years consulting profesional and recently decided to add Salesforce to my skillset, so I'm studying all the trails, modules and books I can get my hands on in order to prepare for a future certification.

As I'm from Spain I'm using Salesforces in Spanish and, in the few days I've been playing with the basic trails and the developer license, I've noticed that many labels (standard fields, picklist values, etc.) show in English. Also there are many cases of bad spelling, bad grammar, and even poor choices for object names that appear to be done by amateurs.

I don't want to be disrespectful but coming from the SAP world is a little shocking that a mayor product like Salesforce seems to be translated not by experts but by someone that "knows Spanish" (but not really).

A clear example of the kind if things you might find is the case of using "Vacaciones" as translation for the "Holidays" configuration in the Company profile. In Spanish, vacaciones refers to the period of time that each worker has for vacationing (like summer vacation). The correct translation for Holidays in the sense it's being used in Salesforce is "Fiestas" that means a date that nobody has to work like Christmas or 4th of July.

That translation is confusing at first for any Spanish user and when you realize what it really is you get a very poor sensation. Like not much effort went into the translation work.

(Again I don't really want to come of as pedant or knowitall, it's is just the way I express myself. Please bear with me since my intentions are to be as constructive as possible)

The point of my question is not to make blood but to ask if there is a place where one can contribute to better translations? Must I create a case for all the errors I find? Can I do that with just a developers license? Where?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I know there is a Translation workbench, but if I'm not wrong that's only for custom fields...

Comment: Your best bet probably *is* just to open a case and see if it gets you anywhere (don't hold your breath). Unfortunately, even if 100% of native Spanish speakers would agree with your assessment about any particular translation, it may still be perceived as pedantry by the people on the receiving end of your feedback. Still, it is a laudable goal to try to improve this state of affairs.

Answer (score 4):

Open a case with Salesforce and report it as a bug. I mean, that's what I would do if there was a misspelling in the English terms.